# How to convert a string (multi-byte) in to a int/hex value in VBScript

Tags: string, input, vbscript, type-conversion

I've requirement for getting a 4-byte hex value as a input, for which I'm using **InputBox()**, which is returning me the input value (for ex: 5C0F591C) as a string and hence it is failing when I'm comparing it with numerical equivalent.

By googling I found how to convert a char to int, I'd like to know if there are any procedures which can convert my 4-byte string in to a int/hex.

Also, it'd helpful if you can point to type conversion in VBScript for future purposes.

I'm very new to VBScript, correction can be made at any point, if I'm wrong

Appreciate your help, in advance.

Comment: CLng("&h5c0f591c") will convert. Remember in VBS we use 16 bit terms so a CLng converts to a 32 bit integer.

Comment: Be aware that Intel puts least significant byte first, so you read an int backwards by twos. So you may need to do 1c590f5c

Comment: @Noodles, I'm getting the following error:"Variables uses an Automation type not supported in VBScript" for the above suggested.

Comment: @Noodles, This is my code
Dim a
a=InputBox("Enter the CRC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "For example if CRC is 0xABCD1234" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Enter ABCD1234 (in upper-case)", "CRC InputBox", "Input Field")
'MsgBox(a)
CLng("&h5c0f591c")
Clng("&H5C0F591C")
CLng(a)'

Comment: You have to concatenate terms with `&`. Also to CLng a number with ABCDEF in it you need to concatenate &H to it. `a=InputBox("Enter the CRC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "For example if CRC is 0xABCD1234" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Enter ABCD1234 (in upper-case)", "CRC InputBox", "Input Field")
 
MsgBox a  & " " & CLng("&h5c0f591c")  & " " & Clng("&H5C0F591C")  & " " &  CLng("&h" & a)`

Comment: @Noodles, This working good for me, Thanks. And also I've worked the other way round as it is a bit convenient. That is I converted my local variable to a string (Cstr(Hex(myVar))) and compared it with the output of InputBox(). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Noodles, can you post same as the answer, so that the question will be looking as answered. It might be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to concatenate terms with &. Also to CLng a number with ABCDEF in it you need to concatenate &H to it.

```
a=InputBox("Enter the CRC" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "For example if CRC is 0xABCD1234" & Chr(13) & Chr(10) & "Enter ABCD1234 (in upper-case)", "CRC InputBox", "Input Field") 
MsgBox a & " " & CLng("&h5c0f591c") & " " & Clng("&H5C0F591C") & " " & CLng("&h" & a)`
```

Comment: The answer will work well for 2's compliment representation, which basically means 0xAABBCCDD will be converted to -1430532899 (signed conversion) instead of 2864434397 (for unsigned conversion). As I need a unsigned conversion, I found this link (which has code for unsigned conversion) and is useful __https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/08/30/putting-your-own-hex-on-your-vbscript/__